# When moving to new URL with Chrome console, is there a way to keep variables alive?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm totally new to JavaScript either Chrome console.

My search of the literature was not enough to answer the question.

But I found it is hard to find any previous questions which tell me "How to prevent variable flushing(?) when you move to new URL in Chrome console".

For example, Let's say right now I'm in Google Starting Page ("https://www.google.com/")

Then I open Chrome console, make integer variable and function like this...

```
a = 10

function myFunc(){
    console.log("Hello")
}
```

After that, I move to Yahoo homepage with this code

```
this.document.location = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
```

Then, as you can expect, my previously defined variable and function are *GONE*.

When I try to call my previous variable **`a`** in Yahoo,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Until now I'm stuck on this problem.

I wonder how to tell browser to keep variables and functions *alive* whenever moving to new URL?

Comment: You can't, the end.

Comment: @deceze♦ i fear deceze is right :(

Comment: Yep, he's right. maybe I must find another way.

Comment: Though this question has been closed, but I found using Chrome driver with python Selenium module would be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you do in the console, you do in the context of the current page (its `window` global object and local scope). If you change the page, this context is gone.

But you can quickly re-initialize the state if you use a scratchpad script in the "Sources" tab (and "Snippets" subtab) of the developer tools. Just create a new script and press Ctrl+S. Then you can select "Run" in the context menu of this script each time the page is changed and the state will be re-created:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the concept of "context". The Snippets seem to be the practical way for me, right now.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, however If you wanna "save" some values you can send them to your server (as ajax request with json) or put them as your link parameter e.g. https://your.server.com/save?a=valueOfA (of course that server must support this parameter and return response which will set proper values to proper variables)

Comment: Not that any of that preserved *variables in the console*, nor that you could preserve functions with it…

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll have a look ajax, as you recommended.

Answer (score -1):

you can use  `localStorge()` to save data on client browser it wont work for function tho just wanted to mention it

Comment: Not that this would preserve *variables* or functions, or work cross-domain…

Comment: I newly saw the "localStorage" in this reply, so I searched in Google and reached to MDZ web doc where the explanation exists. They said "... they stay intact through page loads.". When I tried localStorage["a"] = "Hello", this thing remains even after page_refreshing! But unfortunately the localStorage was not valid after moving to other URL (but stayed alive when go back to the original web page). It's fun to me. Maybe the localStorage only valid in that specific context. Thanks anyway!